# Reverse Proxy that does not buffer uploads

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, upload

From what I've seen of various reverse proxies (nginx, apache, varnish), they seem to buffer file uploads to disk before handing them off to the service they're proxying for.  I need a reverse proxy that doesn't do this; I have a system that handles uploads itself, and buffering uploaded files to disk is not something that works for me.  Does anybody know of a proxy server that can be configured to just pass traffic through to the proxied services without doing any buffering to disk?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Nginx file buffering by setting `proxy_max_temp_file_size` to 0. The documentation on this directive says as much:

> The zero value disables buffering of responses to temporary files.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think that Apache ProxyPassReverse did any buffering to disk. Doing some quick reading, it looks like you have to use mod_disk_cache to enable using the disk - so out of the box, I don't think that it will do what you think it's doing.

Comment: Ok, I must have mis-remembered that.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Neither HAProxy nornginx do any disk buffering for proxying, unless you configure it to do so explicitly (only possible with nginx).